# AngularJS $resource success and error callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple code here that works however I wanted to display the success and error callbacks. This is my code:

```
angular
    .module('studentInfoApp')
    .factory('Student', Student)
    .controller('StudentsController', StudentsController)
    .config(config);

function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        controller: 'StudentsController',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/student-list.html'
    })
}

function Student($resource) {
    return $resource('/students');
}

function StudentsController(Student, $scope, $http) {

    Student.query(function(data) {
        $scope.students = data;
    });

}
```

As you can see the `function Student()` just returns the resource but I can't get the success and error callback if I use the `.then` for example. Am I missing something here? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```js
Student.query(function(data, headers) {
  // OK
  $scope.students = data;
}, function(response) {
  // KO
});
```

Another one using the promise directly:

```js
Student.query().$promise.then(function(response) {
  // OK
  $scope.students = response.data;
}, function(response) {
  // KO
});
```

Comment: What is the use of the 2nd parameter (headers ) in the function there ?

Comment: `headers` is a function that allows you to have access to the response headers, e.g. `headers("Content-Type")`. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#usage, section `Returns`.

Comment: Oh, that's nice. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When using angular $resources you can just save the query directly to your variable. It will then hold the promise and when data returns the data itself.

If you need to handle success/error you can just use the saved promise and add success and error callbacks like below.

```
$scope.students = Student.query();
$scope.students.$promise.then( function(response) {
     console.log('success');
}, function (error) {
    console.log('error');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working, but if there are better ways to do it please feel free to post it also. This is my code now:

```
function StudentsController(Student, $scope) {

    Student.query(function(data) {
        $scope.students = data;
    })
    .$promise.then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log('success');
    }, function errorCallback(error) {
            console.log('error');
    });

}
```